# February and strtotime

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

okay?

I'm trying to hit a calculation date here, however I am not getting ..

What happens is the following:

```
$AtualMenos3 = date("m-d-Y", strtotime("2013-03-31 -3 month"));
$AtualMenos2 = date("m-d-Y", strtotime("2013-03-31 -2 month"));
$AtualMenos1 = date("m-d-Y", strtotime("2013-03-31 -1 month"));
$AtualMes = date("m-d-Y", strtotime("2013-03-31"));
```

The correct should be:

```
03-31-2013
02-28-2013
01-31-2013
12-31-2012
```

However, this php calculating the date wrong, because when month is February (which only has 28 days) the calculation goes wrong ..

Real output:

```
03-31-2013
03-03-2013
01-31-2013
12-31-2012
```

Does anyone know give me a light on how I fix this? because this complicated .. I'm out of ideas ... I can not think of anything: \

Comment: Shouldn't `2013-03-31 -3 month` give `2012-12-31`? Maybe `strtotime` doesn't work like you expect it to? Perhaps are more robust solution is to split the data into it's parts: day, month and year and just substract 3 from the month.

Comment: Strtotime is not advisable for mathetical operation, use DateTime::add or sub()

Comment: Can you please also try date('m-d-Y', strtotime('-1 month', strtotime('2013-03-31')))

Comment: I tried using the DataTime, however it is the same error;

Comment: @ Amit, I tried the way you said however it is the same ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $datetime = new DateTime('2013-03-31');
    $datetime->modify('-1 month');
    echo $datetime->format('Y-m-t') . "<br>";
    $datetime->modify('-1 month');
    echo $datetime->format('Y-m-t') . "<br>";
    $datetime->modify('-1 month');
    echo $datetime->format('Y-m-t') . "<br>";
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0hR8a0)

Comment: ! Look it worked! I also tried with DataTime, however I used the -> sub ("P1A") and was given the same error. But as it worked properly! Thank you!

Comment: actually did not work. Just checked here that you were picking up the last day "t" and not using a past date. What happens is that this date is variable because it comes from a previous input, and therefore could not be so.

Comment: You can change the `t` to `d` to get the date. I assumed you wanted the last day of the month which is why I used `t`.

Comment: I know, but if I put "d", we return to the initial problem. My solution was to create a function to check the month if the month = 2, it checks if the day is 30 or 31 if he puts (if leap) 28/29. Unfortunately or fortunately had to be that way.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to find the last day of the month would be:

```
 $lastDay = date("m-d-Y",(strtotime('next month',strtotime(date("m-01-Y"))) - 1));
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: First thanks for the help! The problem is that the 31 can be variable, because it is an input field on the form where you enter the date you want to view the records.

Comment: Then I'm afraid `strtotime` won't help... :-(

Comment: I think I will have to create a function that checks the month, if it is 2, check the days when 30/31, if there is leap year, and give rather put 27/28.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with `strtotime()`, you can easily calculate the last day of a month by subtracting one day from the next month.

```
echo date("m-d-Y", strtotime("Apr 2013 -1 day")); // yields 03-31-2013
echo date("m-d-Y", strtotime("Mar 2013 -1 day")); // yields 02-28-2013
echo date("m-d-Y", strtotime("Feb 2013 -1 day")); // yields 01-31-2013
```