# Is comparing MySQL dates string formats in PHP correct?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have been comparing mysql dates in php by doing this:

```
<?php

strtotime('2007-12-12 10:00:01') > strtotime('2007-12-12 10:00:00')
```

I just found out that if you compare 2 dates (format `Y-m-d H:i:s`) in php directly, that the result seems to be ok. I've searched [google for this](https://www.google.com/search?q=compare+mysql+string+dates+in+php), no results were found.

**Example 1:**

```
<?php

var_dump('2006-12-12 10:00:00' > '2006-12-12 10:00:00');
var_dump('2006-12-12 10:00:00' >= '2006-12-12 10:00:00');
var_dump('2006-12-12 10:00:00' <= '2006-12-12 10:00:00');
var_dump('2006-12-12 10:00:00' < '2006-12-12 10:00:00');
```

**Result 1:**

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

**Example 2:**

```
<?php

var_dump('2007-12-12 10:00:00' > '2006-12-12 10:00:01');
var_dump('2007-12-12 10:00:00' >= '2006-12-12 10:00:01');
var_dump('2007-12-12 10:00:00' <= '2006-12-12 10:00:01');
var_dump('2007-12-12 10:00:00' < '2006-12-12 10:00:01');
```

**Result 2:**

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

It appears that php is comparing 2 mysql dates correctly. **Is this `a` correct way of comparing mysql dates in php?**

Comment: You are comparing strings, not timestamps. it's more a coincidence that the "timestamp strings" sort properly as strings.

Comment: either you convert those to seconds or use DateTime classes

Comment: [The lexicographical order of the representation... corresponds to chronological order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'2007-12-12 10:00:00' > '2006-12-12 10:00:01'` compares **two strings lexically**. This *incidentally* happens to work if both strings have the same format (i.e. numbers and hyphen or colons in the exact same spots) and if the order of elements is most-significant to least-significant (i.e. year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds).

So, *jein*. It's not incorrect since it actually does work, but the fact that is does work is more or less incidental. It simply seems like a brittle solution which could easily break, while explicitly parsing the date using `strtotime` and comparing explicit timestamp values is a lot less brittle. (Note that `strtotime` also depends on the string being a certain know format though, it won't magically parse any and all values for you.)

Comment: Could anybody please point me to the bit in the PHP manual where this is documented?

Comment: Ah, thanks! I was looking only at the translated version of that page, which seems to miss quite a lot.

Comment: So, the basic idea is that I should use it with caution (might give unexpected results) and strtotime is the way to go. However, it appears that [strtotime fails sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15638540/1057527) as well.

Comment: @deceze: Do you see any case where a comparison like `'2007-12-12 10:00:00' > '2006-12-12 10:00:01'` fails?

Comment: @machine People tend to treat `strtotime` as some magic function which understands any and all date related things you throw at it, which it obviously doesn't (nothing does). So yes, it does "fail" for input which it doesn't support. The manual lists what it does and doesn't support: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php. As long as your dates are positive (nothing before year 0) and always follow the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS` format, simple string comparison shouldn't fail. But again, it feels icky to me. :)